# When I switched from ApacheHttpTransport to NetHttpTransport IOException is thrown instead of HttpResponseException for 401 http status

Tags: android, google-api-java-client

When I switched from ApacheHttpTransport to NetHttpTransport IOException is thrown instead of HttpResponseException for 401 http status.

I get IOException with following message: Received "authentication challenge is null"

This is wrong. I should get HttpResponseException with 401 status. Does anybody faced same problem?

Comment: I get IOException insted of HttpResponseException. So the question is about how can I solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem. On server side I haven't added header "WWW-Authenticate". This response header is required for 401 responses.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- watch for the `IOException`, or
- don't switch to `NetHttpTransport`, or
- write your own custom transport to do what you appear to want (have something that has nothing to do with Apache HttpClient thrown an HttpClient-specific exception)

Comment: But this is bug. 401 status should be handled by HttpResponseException.

Comment: @AlexeyZakharov: "But this is bug" -- that seems unlikely. `HttpResponseException` **is only used by `HttpClient`**. `ApacheHttpTransport` uses `HttpClient`. `NetHttpTransport` does not use `HttpClient`. Since `NetHttpTransport` does not use `HttpClient`, `HttpResponseException` is not involved.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/source/browse/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/http/HttpResponseException.java is Google Http Client Class. And it works well with all statuses except 401